# VBA ERROR : object variable or with block variable not set

Tags: vba, excel

vba error: object variable or with block variable not set

I have no idea what has just happened! Please help. Here is my code!

```
  If intMsgBox = vbYes Then
Unload frmNewOrder // error here
Unload Main_Menu //error here
ActiveSheet.PrintPreview
wkbNewOrder.Worksheets("New Order").Select
wkbNewOrder.Worksheets("New Order").Delete
wkbNewOrder.Worksheets("Main Menu").Select
End If
```

Comment: what are `frmNewOrder` and `Main_Menu` ?

Comment: How do you get *two* errors? Doesn't the code stop after the first one?

Comment: + 1 LOL@Jean-FrançoisCorbett: That was also the first thing that came to my mind... :)

Answer (score 4):

[As explained in the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264506.aspx), neither Main_Menu nor frmNewOrder were set.

Screenshot of the link. In case the above link dies.

[image]

Comment: + 1 That sums it all :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you declared frmNewOrder as a variable but you did not set it and your code looks like this:

```
Dim MyForm As UserForm1
Unload MyForm
```

But it should be instead:

```
Dim MyForm As UserForm
Set MyForm = UserForm1
Unload MyForm
```